# 'triangle 90' is not working for loops in TikZ

Tags: tikz-arrows

I wanted my [finite-state automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_automaton) (FSA) edges' endpoint to transform to an inner filled triangle. Hence I used `triangle 90` as in the below code:

```
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    -triangle 90,
    node distance=3cm,
    every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
    initial text=$ $
]
\node[state, initial] (q1) {$q_1$};
\node[state, accepting, right of=q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\node[state, right of=q2] (q3) {$q_3$};
\draw
(q1) edge[loop above] node{0} (q1)
(q1) edge[above] node{1} (q2)
(q2) edge[loop above] node{1} (q2)
(q2) edge[bend left, above] node{0} (q3)
(q3) edge[bend left, below] node{0,1} (q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But the outcome was as below:

[image: The outcome]

I want my loops to be as the other edges.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the option `-triangle 90` by the two options `->` (all edges are directed) and `>=triangle 90` (all arrows are triangles). My guess would have been that these two ways are equivalent, but apparently they are not.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ->,
    >=triangle 90,
    node distance=3cm,
    every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
    initial text=$ $
]
\node[state, initial] (q1) {$q_1$};
\node[state, accepting, right of=q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\node[state, right of=q2] (q3) {$q_3$};
\draw
(q1) edge[loop above] node{0} (q1)
(q1) edge[above] node{1} (q2)
(q2) edge[loop above] node{1} (q2)
(q2) edge[bend left, above] node{0} (q3)
(q3) edge[bend left, below] node{0,1} (q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 6):

`arrows` is deprecated. Use `arrows.meta`.

Every `loop` style is initially `style, initially ->,shorten >=1pt` and it thereby overwrites the arrowhead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ->,
    >={Triangle[angle=90:5pt]},
    node distance=3cm,
    every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
    initial text=$ $
]
\node[state, initial] (q1) {$q_1$};
\node[state, accepting, right of=q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\node[state, right of=q2] (q3) {$q_3$};
\draw
(q1) edge[loop above] node{0} (q1)
(q1) edge[above] node{1} (q2)
(q2) edge[loop above] node{1} (q2)
(q2) edge[bend left, above] node{0} (q3)
(q3) edge[bend left, below] node{0,1} (q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Automata diagram with right angle arrowheads]

It would be nicer to also shorten the other arrows, `shorten >=1pt` :

[image: Same automata with shortened arrows]